# Umbraco Rest Extension Not working after moving code from 4.7.1 into 4.11.10

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, umbraco

I have recently moved my code from 4.7.1 to 4.11.10. In old version rest extensions used to work perfectly. But in 4.11.10 it's not working and I am getting 500 error. Even debug is also not hitting there.

URL for the rest methon `http://localhost/Base/Landing/GetCountries/3`

NOTE:- I have not upgraded the umbraco. I just moved my code to higher version after installing it

Below is the code snippet

```
namespace Test.Umbraco.Ajax
{

[RestExtensionAttribute("Landing")]
public class Landing : Core.AjaxBase
{

    [RestExtensionMethodAttribute]
    public static string GetCountries()
    {
        return Core.RazorRenderer.RenderScriptFile("LandingPage/GetCountries", 0, GetLandingParameters(false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the upgrade documentation to see if there are any breaking changes. Also, ensure that ALL the code is moved, e.g. any application_start/global.asax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your code is throwing an exception and this gets converted to a 500 error that masks it.
So the problem could be anything. I had the same issue and the best thing I did was wrap all my code inside a try/catch and return the exception as a string. Remember that in order to get all the info from the exception you need to compile in Debug mode and copy the .pdb file along with your .dll.

```
...

[RestExtensionMethodAttribute]
public static string GetCountries() {
 try {
  return Core.RazorRenderer.RenderScriptFile("LandingPage/GetCountries", 0, GetLandingParameters(false));
 } catch (Exception e) {
   return e.ToString();
 }
}

...
```

Hope this helps you find the problem ! It worked for me.